# asp.net mvc : multiple layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

I have a main layout(layout1) of my website as a start page and now I want to add another page(layout) that gets some information from user and then after saving the information in database render the main layout.

right now in start page :

```
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

and in layout :

```
  <div id="main" class="container">
            @RenderBody()
            @RenderSection("~/Views/AskGroup/_Layout1.cshtml");}
        </div>
```

the error : Section not defined: "~/Views/AskGroup/_Layout1.cshtml". how should I add thid layout1 to the layout page? do I need to add a controller as well ?

Comment: `RenderSection` is meant to render a defined `section`, what is the actual content of `_Layout1.cshtml`?

Comment: it's a form for getting information from user. I want to first render this form as a seprate page and then after user entered the information render the layout1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's basic HTML content, use `RenderPartial` instead:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Layout1.cshtml");
```